# MYSQL - How to match the country with the highest deaths for a unique list of continents

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find the country with the highest number of deaths in each continent. So far, I have the following code which gives me the continent and the highest number of deaths, but I am unable to get the country, as shown in the image 'Code without Country'

```
SELECT         
    continent,
    MAX(total_deaths) as AllDeaths
FROM covid.covid_
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY continent
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

[Code without Country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS6gP.png)

However, if I add country to my code, I no longer have what I need

```
SELECT
    continent,
    country,
    MAX(total_deaths) as AllDeaths
FROM covid.covid_
WHERE continent IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY continent, country
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

[Code with Country included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHQCK.png)

As you can see in the 2nd image, now I have multiple results for each continent, which is not what I need - I need a unique list of all continents, along with the country contributing to the highest deaths in each continent

Comment: Schema of your database would be helpful

Comment: Not to mention some sample data as described in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to just add a correlated subquery to your first query to retrieve the country with the highest `total_deaths` value for each continent:

```
select Continent,
    (select country from covid.covid_ c2 where c2.continent = c.continent order by total_deaths desc limit 1) as Country,
    Max(total_deaths) as AllDeaths
from covid.covid_ c
where continent is not null
group by continent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select b.continent, b.country, a.total_deaths
    from (
        SELECT         
        continent,
        MAX(total_deaths) as AllDeaths
        FROM covid.covid_
        WHERE continent IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY continent) as a 
    inner join covid.covid_ as b on a.total_deaths = b.total_deaths and a.continent = b.continent
```

Answer (score 0):

For both MySQL 8.0 and before:

```
-- MySQL 8.0+

WITH cte AS (
        SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY continent ORDER BY total_deaths DESC) AS n
          FROM covid AS t
     )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE n = 1
;
```

Result:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+---+
| country  | continent  | total_deaths | n |
+----------+------------+--------------+---+
| country2 | continent1 |        10001 | 1 |
| country4 | continent2 |        10012 | 1 |
| country5 | continent2 |        10012 | 1 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---+
```

```
-- MySQL 8.0, 5.7 or before:

SELECT *
  FROM covid
 WHERE (continent, total_deaths) IN (
        SELECT continent, MAX(total_deaths)
          FROM covid
         GROUP BY continent
       )
;
```

Result:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
| country  | continent  | total_deaths |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| country2 | continent1 |        10001 |
| country4 | continent2 |        10012 |
| country5 | continent2 |        10012 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Given the following data:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
| country  | continent  | total_deaths |
+----------+------------+--------------+
| country1 | continent1 |        10000 |
| country2 | continent1 |        10001 |
| country3 | continent2 |        10011 |
| country4 | continent2 |        10012 |
| country5 | continent2 |        10012 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```